# values of design variables out of their bounds and contraints seems like being ignored

Tags: openmdao

It happened many times that the values of design variables were out of their bounds (for example, low bound 0.0, design variable value was set to -0.004 by the optimizer), and the constraints seemed like being ignored (for example, a minimum 1.0 constraint for an output variable was not satisfied).

I am using openMDAO version 1.6.4, ScipyOptimizer, SLSQP, force_fd, step_size 1.0e-4.

Any ideas about why those things happened? Am I doing settings wrong? possible bugs? if not, how to avoid?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: If you could please edit your question to add some code to show us how you're setting things up, we might be able to better help you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

without seeing any code, its hard to know for sure. But SLSQP has been known to violate variable bounds, especially when design variables are poorly scaled. Try scaling things so your design variables vary to between 0 and 1. That should help it work better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Justin, that explains a lot.
I did not scale the design variables to [0,1]. I will re-run my codes with scaled variables.
(If every thing will be working correctly, no further followup will be provided)

Regards,

Henry

Answer (score 0):

It took me quite some time to re-run my codes with scaled variables.

I got converged results, and values of all design variables are within their bounds, however, one constraint is still not satisfied. I set a constraint for a parameter to be [0, 1.5], but the final result is 1.73.

I am thinking of applying a more strict convergence criterion and re-running my codes to see if the constraint will be satisfied.

Do you think a smaller convergence criterion will help satisfy all the constraints? Your advice will be appreciated.